# Is JUnit5 backward compatible to JUnit4?

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I did google quite a bit; but I could neither find a source saying "of course it is" nor one going "no, it isn't; and here it breaks".

We have about 2000 unit tests of very varying quality, using EasyMock, PowerMock, Mockito; and I am simply wondering: is there a reasonable chance that those 2000 testcases just work when switching to JUnit5; or is that so unlikely that I better not spend a single second trying?

In other words: I am looking for answers that can confirm "yes, it worked for our large code base"; or "no, it is not at all that easy".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As stated by the [JUnit 5 User Guide](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#migrating-from-junit4-running):

> Just make sure that the junit-vintage-engine artifact is in your test runtime path. In that case JUnit 3 and JUnit 4 tests will automatically be picked up by the JUnit Platform launcher.
>
> See the example projects in the [junit5-samples](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples) repository to find out how this is done with Gradle and Maven.

Answer (score 2):

http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/

`junit-vintage-engine` is for running junit4 or 3 so it looks like it 
'JUnit Vintage test engine implementation that allows to run vintage JUnit tests, i.e. tests written in the JUnit 3 or JUnit 4 style, on the new JUnit Platform.'

Answer (score 0):

My current assessment regarding regarding our projects is to stay with JUnit 4.12 for the moment.

As of now, we our build setup is "different" for eclipse and our "backend build"; meaning: we can't use maven/gradle to build within eclipse. And I simply failed to just identify/download the JARs I would need to replace the junit-4.12.jar within our eclipse setup; not even thinking about also providing some (but which) other JARs in order to have JUnit 5 available.